# Creating AdBanner resets my Scene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I would like to show a iAd Banner when the player dies in my SpriteKit Game (using Swift).
When the player dies the menu / highscore and a restart button is shown.

If I create a AdBannerView when the menu is schon my whole GameScene is reseted like when I just loaded the Scene.

My code to create an ADBanner in GameViewController:

```
    var adView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectZero)
    adView.delegate = self
    adView.hidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(adView)
```

Does the addSubview reload my whole scene?
How can I prevent that?

My first idea was to create the ADBanner at the beginning and simply hiding and unhiding it when I need it. But hiding Ads and letting them cycle through although nobody sees them seems... not good?

Comment: From where in your view controller subclass are you presenting the scene?

Comment: I call the code from above by sending a NSNotification from my GameScene to my GameViewController. 

I only want to add a banner when the menu pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time a subview is added viewWillLayoutSubviews() is called.
After putting everything I had in viewWillLayoutSubviews() to viewDidLoad() the scene stayed the way it was.